# How to change attachment of Outlook .msg file with Apache POIFS/HSMF

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi, email-attachments

I am working on some project that requires changing attachments of an Outlook .msg file.

I chosen to use Apache POI with its low-level POIFS API.

I am able to substitute binary data of an attachments by re-writing PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ ByteChunk, as well as few other Chunks related to filename, extension, displayName.

However, when I open the resulting .msg file in outlook my attachments viewed as no-extension file but content is exact what I have pushed to it:

[image]

There are two more fields that I can't find possible data to write as well as there is no description for them in MAPIProperty.Java POI dictionary:

[image]

Can somebody advice me how I can make attachment substitution possible to success? What kind of data I have to put into these two fields in order to fix preview? Will this help?

I am looking for a free solution. I already tried Aspose.Email and this works brilliant but it is not currently an option.

Answer (score 0):

Embedded message attachment (stored in PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ property on an attachment) is not a file.

Does Outlook correctly open the attachment? Make sure the attachment type remains the same.